# Find the derivative of the following: $H(x)= \int_0^x \frac{1}{\sin(t)}dt$ and $I(x)= \int_0^{x^2}2^sds$

Tags: integration, derivatives, riemann-integration

Find the derivative of the following with $x \in [\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2}]$:

$$H(x)= \int_0^x \frac{1}{\sin(t)}dt$$
and $$I(x)= \int_0^{x^2}2^sds$$

I said that since both of the functions are continuous on $[\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2}]$, both of the functions inside the integral are Riemann integrable, by the Fundamental theorem of Calculus, and hence $H(x)$ and $I(x)$ are continuous on the same interval and $H'(x) = \frac{1}{\sin(x)} $ and $I'(x) = 2^{x^2}$

Is this correct?

Comment: Hint: Use the Leibnitz Rule for differentiation of an integral.

Comment: There is an issue with $H$ since $\csc(x)$ is not integrable near $0$: $\frac{1}{\sin t}=\frac{t}{\sin t}\frac{1}{t}\sim \frac{1}{t}$ as $t\rightarrow0$; so near $0$, say on an interval of the form $(0,\varepsilon)$ $\int_{(0,\varepsilon}\frac{1}{\sin t}\,dt=\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{1}{\sin t}dt \ge \int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{1}{x}dx \to \text{ diverges}$$

Nor is correct the second.$$I(x) = \int_0^{x^2} 2^sds = \mathcal I(x^2)$$
where $\mathcal I(x) := \int_0^x 2^s ds$. Then, since $\mathcal I'(x) = 2^x$, we have
$$I'(x) = \left[\mathcal I(x^2)\right]' = 2x\cdot\mathcal I'(x^2) = 2x\cdot 2^{x^2}$$

Also, see [Leibniz's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) for more information.

Comment: H is not finite.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Oops, yes, that diverges. Thank you!

Comment: It does not make much sense to mix definite integrals with indefinite integrals as you did for $I$. $I(x)$ is imply the composition of two functions, namely $I(x)=G(x^2)$ where $G(t)=\int^t_0 2^s\,ds$. Other than that, your solution would be ok.

Comment: @OliverDiaz When we are to find $\int_a^b f(x)dx$, don't we find the primitive of $f(x)$ that is $F(x) = \int f(x)dx$ and find the difference $F(b)-F(a)$?

Comment: The point is that all you need here is to apply the fundamental theorem of calculus that states that if $F(x)=\int^x_a f(s)\,ds$ and $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, then $F'(x_0)=f'(x_0)$. No need of primitives.

Comment: @OliverDiaz I got your point. It seems I am writing the definite integral as $F(x) - F(a)$ where $F(s) = \int f(s)ds$ and you did it as $F(x) = \int_a^x f(s)ds$. Of course, the last notation is the most recommended one, but writing it as a difference was more comprehensible when I was a student learning myself these stuff. Thank you for your comments. I will edit my answer soon!

Comment: @VIVID: all I am trying to get across is that in using the fundamental theorem of calculus (or rather the first fundamental of calculus) one does not need to go and find antiderivatives: for (1) you are differentiating and (2) what if the antiderivative does not exists (in terms of elementary functions, as in Liouville's theorem on derivative fields)? For example $G(x)=\int^{x^2}_0 e^{t^2}\,dt$. If I want $G'(x)$, the first fundamental theorem of Calculus suffices. Implying the use of an antiderivative is misleading in this case, for there is no such one (in the sense of Liouville).

Comment: @OliverDiaz Thank you. Now, fully got your point.